# pde.exportFeatures for features in the target?

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have feature `abc` in my target file, and I want to copy it to a local folder. I use the ant build file with the command `pde.exportFeatures`.

Yet I get the following error message:

```
Buildfile: C:\...\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\.bundle_pool\features\abc.feature_1.6.1\build.xml does not exist
```

Is `pde.exportFeatures` not meant to be used for features in the target file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pde.exportFeatures is only intended to be used for features in your workspace not in the target platform.

Comment: So how do you export features in your target?

Comment: Features in the target platform are normally already in the export format.

Comment: Sure they are but if you want to copy them into a deploy folder, what ant command do you use?